# After updates Ubuntu works very slow etc

Tags: updates, firefox

So yesterday I got a notification of some available updates, in all honesty I haven't looked at what updates these were. I just followed all the updates as usual.

Now when I start up my laptop, first of all I notice that it takes *just* a little longer to startup then before (which doesn't bother me).
But whenever I open an application it takes way too long before it starts, or it doesn't start at all. 
My main problem is that Firefox doesn't respond at all. After 5 minutes or longer I get an error message saying there is already another instance of Firefox running and that I should close it, or restart my laptop. Neither of those worked unfortunately. Seeing I'm not that advanced with Ubuntu yet, I don't know what would be the best solution.

Should/can I recover to an earlier date before the updates? And if so; how?
Or is this related to something else?

I will appreciate it very much if someone will help me with this!!!

Comment: Have you ran the System Monitor to see if there is a run away process or something?

Comment: That sounds completely like Chinese to me honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your main issue (so far) is realistically just with Firefox.

Have you tried to uninstall/reinstall Firefox yet?

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Try that, and let us know if that fixes Firefox.  I wouldn't revert basic OS updates as of yet, as a newer user to Ubuntu.

Comment: Perfect, it works now thanks a lot! Do you think this also caused the slow startup from other applications? It goes faster now though, but to me it seems a bit unreal that Firefox affects this.

Comment: I'm glad that fixed it.  Unfortunately, I can't really give any feedback as to why or how it could have been the cause.  Just guessing that it's possible Firefox could have been trying to restore previous browser sessions closed during the update installation.. but that's entirely hypothetical, and only you would know if that were the case during the updates.  (i.e. : Firefox was trying to restore a session, failed, crashed, restore a session, etc. - all in a cyclical loop possibly... which would also explain why it was reporting as, "already running," and as @notkevin said - PerfMonitor saw)